# mvc index action not rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

The following returns "/Settings"

```
Url.Action("Index", "Settings");
```

On my local this renders fine. However on my remote machine I get the error belows. I get the impression that the controller is not properly instantiated.

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EStore.Domain.ViewModel.SettingsViewModel>'.    

Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<EStore.Domain.ViewModel.SettingsViewModel>" %>
```

Global.asax

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminCompany",
    "{controller}/{action}/{companyId}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", companyId = "", id = "" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Status",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{statusId}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "", statusId = ""}
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Admin",
    "admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```

Index Actions

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = IndexViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the type loader cannot find the `EStore.Domain.ViewModel.SettingsViewModel` class. Make sure this class is included in one of the assemblies in the `bin` folder.

Comment: hi darin, to clarify. "Settings/Index" works. If just that "Settings/" doesn't seem to instantiated the controller.

Comment: to expand, i know EStore.Domain.ViewModel.SettingsViewModel is included in the assembly as "Setting/Index" works. How does the MVC framework know to look in "Index" action if no action is specified.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = IndexViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Should that read var ViewModel = new IndexViewModel();

seems like you might be passing a null through.

Also, where is the route for settings? Is it meant to pick up from the default route using the home controller?

Comment: IndexviewModel is actually a method, this works fine. I believe setting would just use the first route. Weird that it works locally.